# How to enable dynamic debugging in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel

I have enabled the `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` flag in kernel config file. when I boot in my system I am able to mount the`/sys/kernel/debug` and there is `dynamic_debug/control` file too.

But when I issue any command like

```
echo -n 'module nfsd +p' > <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control
```

it does not shows any output in `dmesg` OR `syslogd`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't there be README files in the kernel source that describes how to use this? Have you tried looking at the source of the function that handles the `control` file?

Comment: There is a README, and I think it's clear from the question that he had read it.  But the docs aren't crystal clear.  See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Have you set your log-level?

```
echo 8 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo -n 'module <module name/folder> +p' > <debugfs>/dynamic_debug/control
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<debugfs>` is only a placeholder in the documentation.  For whatever reason, the docs don't mention the actual path were debugfs is mounted.  You can find the path with `mount | grep debugfs`.

For example, on my system:

```
$ mount | grep debug
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)

$ mount | grep debug | awk '{print $3}'
/sys/kernel/debug
```

I doubt it gets mounted to another path on other systems, but I could be wrong.

This command/path should work for you:

`echo -n 'module nfsd +p' > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`