# missing Linux /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug , how to enable?

Tags: linux, debugging, logging, linux-kernel, dmesg

**tl;dr** I want to use Linux "Dynamic Debug" but the path `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/` is not found.

I want to use the "Dynamic Debug" feature of Linux to enable debug messages for a particular kernel module (`wireguard`). To enable a kernel module kernel debug messages requires writing instructions to file `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`,

```
echo module wireguard +p > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

But there is no directory `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/` and thus no file `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control`.
The `debugfs` is mounted to `/sys/kernel/debug/` (as is typical) and it has other files (so it's not like debugfs is mounted unexpectedly). Nor does alternative path `/proc/dynamic_debug/` exist.

Running Linux kernel 5.15.

Comment: Similar to question [How to enable dynamic debugging in the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631968/how-to-enable-dynamic-debugging-in-the-linux-kernel), but that question already has path `/sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug` available. This question occurs "before" that other question.

Comment: [`kernel.org`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.15/admin-guide/dynamic-debug-howto.html) mentions setting `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG`. I think I have to get a Linux built with that enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling "Dynamic Debug" requires setting Linux compilation option `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG`. In my case, I'm using Raspbian, and [that project decided not to enable `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG` during Linux builds](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3486).

I could "roll my own" (compile Raspbian with `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG`) but that's a lot of work and likely will upset the apt package management.